How to geocode addresses to both Census 2010 and Census 2020 boundaries?
I have about 2000 addresses that I need to link to both Census 2010 and Census 2020 boundaries due to the year data collected.
I was able to use the package tidygeocoder to geocode addresses to Census 2020 boundaries. But unsure how to get Census 2010 boundaries.
Here are my codes to get Census 2020 boundaries:
orig_addresses %>%
tidygeocoder::geocode(
street = ADDRESSSTREET,
city = ADDRESSCITY,
state = ADDRESSSTATE,
postalcode = ADDRESSZIPCODE, 
method = "census",
full_results = TRUE,
api_options = list(census_return_type = "geographies")
)

Thank you.
